# How can I install gnome 3.14

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I tried to update my gnome 3.12 to 3.14 with four commands in the terminal but after rebooting only black screen came out, there is no gnome 3.14..... I have to work from tty1, what is wrong with it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
suod apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The section 'How to revert the changes' [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html) may help with this issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 sir

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say, for you did an dist-upgrade, too. Chances are that you installed dozens, if not hundreds of new releases for the programs installed on your computer, and every second one of these may be responsible for your problems.

You should look into the following two files, and see whether there are any error messages:

```
`cat /var/log/boot.log`

`cat /var/log/dmesg`
```